# How to setExceptionListener in Jruby

Tags: jruby

I'm new to Jruby and currently working on an app needs to convert Java code to Jruby for JMS client, here is the code in java:

```
connection.setExceptionListener(ExceptionListener.new() {
      public void onException (JMSException ex) {
                 connection = null;
      }
    })
```

Can anyone give me some idea how to convert this to Jruby? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all that is not valid Java code maybe this is : 

`connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
    public void onException(JMSException ex) {
        connection = null;
    }
})`

... depends on the `ExceptionListener` lets assume its a functional-interface with a single `onException` method in which case you can use the (magical) block-to-interface conversion :

`connection.setExceptionListener { |ex| connection = nil }`